# mysql server shell

Tags: mysql

I have just installed mysql 5.1.36 ,through the latest version of wamp(2..).
The question is how do I get to the **shell prompt** in mysql server, as recommended by mysql server manual.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mysql`/`mysql.exe` client to connect.